With Avalonia, how do I request that my application runs on landscape mode on mobile devices?
I'm trying to make an Avalonia app with focus on desktop, but which could still be somewhat usable on mobile.
I'd like to enforce that my (mobile) application runs only on landscape mode, with Android for starters. How would i go about it with Avalonia ?

Nevermind, i wasn't looking in the right class.
The MainActivity.cs file in the Android project has an [Activity] Attribute, which can be parameterized with ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Landscape
This does the trick quite simply.
